# Firefox / display flex / option text overflows

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

The text of the disabled option of the `select` tag overflows ugly in Firefox (tested on Windows and Linux) when using flex the following way:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='text'>
  <select>
    <option value='' disabled selected>something goes here</option>
    <option value='audi'>audi</option>
    <option value='volvo'>volvo</option>
    <option value='bmw'>bmw</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lukm1j66/1/

See an image missing the end of text:

[image]

No problem with Chrome (and other Webkit engines) or IE or Edge. Any idea? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage the way Flexbox works and instruct the select to take up as much room as it needs using `flex-shrink`.

```css
    div { display: flex; }
    input { width: 100%; }
    select { flex-shrink: 0; }
```

```html
<div>
    <input type='text'>
    <select>
        <option value='' disabled selected>something goes here</option>
        <option value='audi'>audi</option>
        <option value='volvo'>volvo</option>
        <option value='bmw'>bmw</option>
    </select>
</div>
```